# How to construct QUERY UPDATE for JSONB field PostgreSQL (I need add a new element)

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I hope you can help me, I'm new using json on postgres. I have a table with the next fields:

```
id (nextval('"mxAddress_id_seq"'::regclass))
jaddress (jsonb)
attributeid (integer)
extraparams (jsonb)
updated (integer)
disabled (boolean)
taggroup (integer)
```

I'm searching how to add a new element making a query by postgres on a jsonb field.

I have this on jaddres:

```
{"label": "UIR88S1-118"}
```

And i want to add: "eu": "P" to this.  Then it must look like this:

```
{"label": "UIR88S1-118", "eu": "P"}
```

If I do it in single mode, the output console says:

```
UPDATE "public"."mxAddress" SET "jaddress" = '{"label": "UIRF124_501-301", "eu": "P"}' WHERE "id" = 420
```

But i need filtering by **attributeId**, because there are 1200 rows for each category and there are 28 categories. For example: If `attributeId = 5` I put `"eu":"P"`, if `attributeId = 10`, then i put `"eu":"MWH"`

Really I don't know how to construct the query.

Thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: UPDATE public.mxAddress
   SET jaddress= jaddress::jsonb ||  ('{"eu":"P"}' )::jsonb where attributeId = 5

Comment: Thanks for answer, I have tried the concat , but give the next error: <br/> [42883] ERROR: operator does not exist: jsonb || jsonb Suggerimento: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts. Posizione: 57

Comment: whats your postgres version ? please print select VERSION()

Comment: This is the version installed on server PostgreSQL 9.4.11

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
UPDATE "public"."mxAddress" SET "jaddress" = "jaddress"::jsonb || '{ "eu": "P"}'::jsonb WHERE attributeId = 5;
```

Likewise for your other `attributeId`'s.

Comment: Thanks so much for answer. But I can't execute the query, because attributeId is not part of the JSON field, it's another field; and the values for label, are all different and these don't must be modified, just I need add a new element without update the rest.

Answer (score 0):

needs postgres >=9.5

to add an element to an jsonb field you can concat them

```
UPDATE "public"."mxAddress" 
   SET jaddress= jaddress::jsonb || ('{"eu":"P"}')::jsonb 
where attributeId = 5
```

for other attributeIds write another update,
to delete an element from an jsonb field use -

Comment: Ahhhh ok!!!! Thanks, and is there some way to make it just with the version  9.4?

Comment: @Lurhy Contreras , have a look at https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-json.html   , maybe json_object('{a, b}', '{1,2}') results in {"a": "1", "b": "2"}